# Twitter API - Listen to a user's tweets in real-time

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to listen to a number of users' (specific users) tweets in real-time using the Twitter API, but I have not been able to find any documentation regarding this. I have found lots of info about listening to tweets that use a certain hashtag or keyword but no info about listening to all tweets from certain users in real-time.

With the Twitter4J API I was able to specify a number of users, create a stream and then have a piece of code run whenever one of the users tweeted. How could I accomplish this with PHP?

Comment: https://github.com/fennb/phirehose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter

> follow
>
> A comma-separated list of user IDs, indicating the users whose Tweets should be delivered on the stream.

So, if you POST `John,Paul,George,Ringo` you will get a stream which includes:

- Tweets created by the user.
- Tweets which are retweeted by the user.
- Replies to the user.
- Retweets of the user.

Comment: How to get just the original tweets by the user, i.e, just the first bullet point?

Comment: @SamChats you should ask this as a new question - but you can just filter them out as you receive them.

Comment: Currently I'm doing exactly that :) But what if I miss tweets from the original user, as the public stream returns just a sample of tweets?

Answer (score 2):

Late response, but have you seen this?

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/overview

## Account Activity API

### Overview

The Account Activity API provides you the ability to subscribe to realtime activities related to a user account via webhooks. This means that you can receive realtime Tweets, Direct Messages, and other account events from one or more of your owned or subscribed accounts through a single connection.

You will receive all related activities below for each user subscription on your webhook registration:

### Activity types

- Tweets (by user)
- Tweet deletes (by user)
- @mentions (of user)
- Replies (to or from user)
- Retweets (by user or of user)
- Quote Tweets (by user or of user)
- Retweets of Quoted Tweets (by user or of user)
- Likes (by user or of user)
- Follows (by user or of user)
- Unfollows (by user)
- Blocks (by user)
- Unblocks (by user)
- Mutes (by user)
- Unmutes (by user)
  *Direct Messages sent (by user)
- Direct Messages received (by user)
  *Typing indicators (to user)
- Read receipts (to user)
- Subscription revokes (by user)

Please note - We do not deliver home timeline data via the Account Activity API. Please use the GET statuses/home_timeline to pull this data.

Comment: Correct me if I am mistaken, but this only allows for ownself and not tracking one or more others.